# Read only asset has no meta file error. UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been getting these error messages in my Unity project.

[image: error messages]

I'm unsure how they came about, and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone explain why those meta files are missing? I like to be able to fix it so it doesn't cause any issues later on.

Currently using Unity 2018.2.12f1. But I was getting the errors before I updated to my current version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a partial solution showing some research I found. It might help.

> Go to console, right click on the package.
>
> Then select open in explorer.
>
> I found that this package was not in the expected
>   Users[username]\Documents file structure. Also the dates were old so
>   it seems my reimports had had no effects. So in windows explorer I
>   deleted the complete package.
>
> Then I reopened the project in Unity, and at package, reimport all.
>
> This fixed it.

[source](https://forum.unity.com/threads/read-only-asset-has-no-meta-file.545654/#post-3604866)

Answer (score 3):

in my MacOS case, i quit unity, deleted everything in `<Path To My Project>/Library/PackageCache`, and relaunched.